# Multi part NSArray Post AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, afnetworking

I have a large NSArray I am wanting to split into chunks and send to my web server, upon completion of each chunk I then need to update the fields in my SQLite DB that relate to each item in each array chunk.

This is the code I am currently running, where I try to use a call back to receive success or failure then update my local SQLite DB where appropriate.

```
- (void)postlowData:(NSArray *)lowMArray Callback:(void (^)(NSError *error, BOOL success))callback;
{
// Currently this method is sending the whole lowMArray
// What I want to do is Split lowMArray into a chunkArray (where chunk is 20 of the leading items from lowMArray)
// I would then send chunkArray with the following code, when I receive a response I then want to update local SQLite DB with result and recall this method to start on the next 20 chunks.
        // Create Json data from lowMArray
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:lowMArray
                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                             error:nil];

        // Construct post request
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lows", _silServerBaseUrl]]];
        request = [self applyAuth:request];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        // Send post request
        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
//                NSLog(@"Response Failed!");
                callback(error, NO);
            } else {
//                NSLog(@"Response Success!");
                callback(error, YES);
                // On success add itmes from lowChunkArray so that you can adjust sent_Flag later
            }
        }];
        [dataTask resume]; // runs task
}
```

The issue I am running into is that when I run this code if I am splitting the array into chunks sending the chunk adjusting the main array for the next chunk I don't get a confirmed callback till the very end of all the requests, at which point I have lost track of what success or failure?

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

### Update

I am now trying to do this using AFHTTPRequestOperation which  seems to be working as a batch upload however the

> setHTTPBody:jsonData

Never seems to make it to the server.

I used this [Batch of Operations example](http://samwize.com/2014/05/10/tutorial-on-using-afnetworking-2-dot-0/) to help me construct this method however as I said above the JSON data never makes it to the server.

```
- (void)postlowData:(NSArray *)lowMArray;
{
    NSLog(@"Syncing Local");

    NSArray *chunklow = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lows", _silServerBaseUrl]];

//Test: creating 10 things to send 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ([lowMArray count] > 0) {
                if ([lowMArray count] >= 20) {
                    low = [lowMArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
                } else if ([lowMArray count] < 20) {
                    low = [lowMArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [lowMArray count])];
                }
            }

        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:low
                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                             error:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        request = [self applyAuth:request];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
    }

    NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
        NSLog(@"Syncing complete");
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem of splitting insertion of a large array into chunks to be inserted to a DB via network operations, an `NSOperationQueue` can be created that will allow you to add a separate operation for each chunk of data to be inserted.

The queue can be set to run in a serial manner so that each operation will need to be complete before the next one is started.

Using a queue makes the multiple operations more manageable than having the flow be controlled by callbacks.

In summary, you create a queue and set its maximum concurrent operation count to 1. Then create an `NSOperation` subclass that performs the necessary steps to insert data into the database. Each chunk of data will correspond to a separate operation that will be added to the queue. Each operation will be performed in series until all are complete.

Here is an outline for the solution:

```
// Create a new queue to hold network operations.
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

// Split the large array into chunks of 20 items each.
NSInteger chunkSize = 20;

NSInteger i = 0;
NSInteger total = [lowMArray count];

while (i < total) {    
    NSInteger j = i;
    NSMutableArray *chunk = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (j < i + chunkSize - 1 && j < total)  {
        [chunk addObject:lowMArray[j]];
        j++;
    }

    MyOperation *myOperation = [[MyOperation alloc] initWithArray:chunk];        
    self.operationQueue.addOperation(myOperation)

    i += chunkSize;
}
```

MyOperation.h:

```
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)chunk;
@property NSArray *chunk;

@end
```

MyOperation.m:

```
@implementation MyOperation

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)chunk
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.chunk = chunk;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    // Create Json data from lowMArray
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.chunk
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:nil];

    // Construct post request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lows", _silServerBaseUrl]]];
    request = [self applyAuth:request];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

     // Send post request
     AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
     NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            // NSLog(@"Response Failed!");
        } else {
            // NSLog(@"Response Success!");
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume]; // runs task
}

@end
```

AFNetworking has support for its own `NSOperation` subclass in `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. An example can be found [here](http://samwize.com/2014/05/10/tutorial-on-using-afnetworking-2-dot-0/). Also, the AFNetworking GitHub repository has an [example for batch operations](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#afhttprequestoperation).

---

**Based on your revised question, setting the completion block of each `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to handle the response and error can help to debug the problem.**

Here is how it is done:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    NSString* decodedResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response %@", decodedResponse);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}];
```

It would be inserted after `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post, I was unable to get this to work however have started looking at the link you have supplied hoping I will find something there using batch operations under AFHTTP 2.0

Comment: I have updated my question showing my new set of code.. if you would be able to help that would be great thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you `NSLog(@"low %@", low);` after `low = [lowMArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [lowMArray count])];`?

Comment: A big array of my data

low (
        {
        Ment = 001;
        Time = "2015-11-10";
        LowId = 3427;
        id = 2;
    },
        {
        Ment = 001;
        Time = "2015-11-10";
        LowId = 3427;
        id = 2;
    },
        {

etc...